# How can I ignore all index.ts files from code coverage in jest? (regex failing error)

Tags: regex, jestjs

I tried to use a regular expression but it fails,

```
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "src/**/index.*"
],
```

ERROR: Invalid regular expression: /src/**/index.*/

```
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "**/index.*"
  ],
```

ERROR: Invalid regular expression: /**/index.*/

Comment: That's a glob pattern, not a regex.

Comment: Thanks, that and the answer below allowed me to get this working. I new it was a glob pattern but it just wasn't registering in my brain that I was trying to force it into a regular expression. Funny how you can ignore the obvious sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my knowledge the thing is `jest` has a snippet to check this pattern like this:

```js
if (
  config.coveragePathIgnorePatterns.some(pattern => !!filename.match(pattern))
) {
  return false;
}
```

From the code above, it uses `match` method which accepts `RegExp` in most cases as argument. However, `jest` has converted `pattern` as string. In case of string, you could just only input a raw string such as: `index.js`, `index.ts`...

In short, I think you just can set up with raw string as above:

```
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
  'index.js',
  'index.jsx',
  'index.ts',
   // ...
],
```